# How to find text using capybara when the text is hidden?

Tags: firefox, capybara

I'm just getting into automated testing, and I've been experimenting with different tests for different browsers. I'm trying to find a specific text on a page (postcode, which has been previously read from a different field) the code I've used worked perfectly fine for Chrome however for Firefox it keeps timing out. I've used page.all() however because it looks through the whole page it takes a while, which is why it times out.

I've tried using find_all() however that did basically the same thing and the same error popped up again. I've also tried to but a sleep() in after the page.all() however that did nothing since the page.all() run first and still timed out.

Is there any other way I can find the postcode on the page?

As a side note, if someone knows how I could scroll down the page instead that would work too since then the text wouldn't be hidden and a basic find() would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a number of inaccuracies so let's correct those first.

1. `page.all`, `page.find_all`, and `find_all` are exactly the same thing - so trying one over the other makes no sense and would make no difference.
2. If the issue was a slow page load and you were going to use sleep you would need to put it before the `page.all` to see any difference - wait for the page to load and then do the search for the element.
3. Your code isn't timing out because `all` takes a while. The time a single run of `all` takes is minimal compared to the default setting for `Capybara.default_max_wait_time`, and the search would actually be run multiple times while waiting for matching elements to occur. It could be timing out because the browser is slow to load the page, but that has nothing to do with the speed of `all`
4. Scrolling the page would only make a difference if the page is being lazy loaded. Text isn't hidden from Capybara because it's below the fold, it's only hidden if it isn't displayed on the page. That would be if it had CSS that caused it to not be shown at all.

Okay - now on to potential solutions.

- You don't show your code or the exact error message you're getting (good practice in the future when asking a question on SO) so I don't know exactly what you're running, but if actually getting a `Timeout` error when using `all` (and you haven't specified any of the count options) then it's more likely the version of geckodriver you're using isn't compatible with the version of Firefox you have. This is because `all` would return an empty array if it didn't find anything, not a timeout error.
- If instead you just mean `all` doesn't find the elements and returns an empty array, then it could just be Firefox is loading this specific page slowly for some reason and you can increase the maximum waiting time with something like `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10`
- If the page is actually lazy loading content so the content really doesn't exist in the page until you scroll to the bottom then you can scroll down the page with

  page.scroll_to :bottom

which should then trigger the lazy loading, although if this was the case I would expect Chrome to fail too (unless you are testing with different window sizes so scrolling wasn't necessary with Chrome but was with Firefox)